# splice method returns an error: is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, methods, splice

I have been trying to make the code below work, which is a part of deletion function.
However, the splice method inside the for-loop keeps returning an error when it's run.

Can anyone please give me a solution to this problem?

```
let games = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('games'));

for (let i =0; i < games.length; i++) {
    if (games[i].gName == gName) {
        console.log('found it');
        games[i].splice(i, 1);
        //Uncaught TypeError: games[i].splice is not a function
    }
}
```

Comment: `games` is an array.  You seem to be getting the element in position `i` of the array and trying to `splice(...)` this element.  I think you mean to `splice(...)` the array at that position instead?

Comment: Yes, that is what I have meant to do. I got confused between the two i: the one in [] and the other one in (). Thank you for elaborating on my problem!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the splice function returns an error because `games[i]` is an object, not an array.
If you want to use splice on the array, just remove the `[i]` part.
`games.splice(i, 1);`

Also you can use `for (i in games)` as a shorthand for `for (let i =0; i < games.length; i++);`

Comment: I really appreciate you help! Now that the whole thing is working!